# Why should i declare my dynamodb resources in the serverless.yml?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I wanna know this because, I'm just starting a new project with serverless & dynamodb. And I'm constantly changing or adding indexes, so everytime I make these changes I can't deploy again due to same table name conflict. And if I make changes to the Resources section all old data is removed.

So is it necessary to define the dynamodb resources (attribs, key, GSI) before hand? Isn't nosql supposed to be flexible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a long discussion about this behavior:
https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3183

In my experience you need to create another project just for dynamodb tables, later you'll need to add autoscaling for every table and it will mess your project totally.

Create another project, build stages DEV/PROD, so in DEV you can delete and add new GSI, key without problem.